# How best to use ApiController with Owin bearer Token to refresh the bearer token

Tags: c#, refresh, owin, bearer-token, asp.net-apicontroller

We have a AJ website
That access data via C# WebApp, that is just using ApiController
And it uses Owin bearer token to allow the AJ client code to access the API.

The API is only access for the AJ website
And it handles the login and return of the token to use.
Where the token and claims is generated but a second webapp that called internally by the main web api.

[image]

These site are working well, and data is flowing with the use of the claims to identify the request.
[image]

What we would like to do is create a request on the Main Api
Where a authenticated token can be passed
We use the claim to know the identity
And return a updated bearer token
So that any roles, or time to expire is updated

So what is best way to re-pass the bearer token provide to the main web api
Across to the Token Service and have it create a new bearer token?

Do we update the simple auth service provider?
Or do we and a new api call on to the token service which we recall, and that generates the new bearer token?

What is best option, and how do we implement it?

Grateful of any thoughts or help on the topic, thanks.
From what I can see is a lot of example of this use, but none of them seem complete with actual usage.
Plus they seem to allow use of a refresh token that the AJ site stores or is in a cookie.
Some examples show that can get a refresh after it has expired.
We want to look at refresh of bearer token before it expires.
 If expired then just have to login again.